# Firebase App initializing app __FIRAPP_DEFAULT (default 1)

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

When I run the game in unity a debug message appears:

```
Firebase App initializing app __FIRAPP_DEFAULT (default 1).
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
Firebase.Platform.FirebaseLogger:LogMessage(PlatformLogLevel, String)
Firebase.FirebaseApp:LogMessage(LogLevel, String)
Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE:FirebaseApp_CreateInternal__SWIG_0()
Firebase.FirebaseApp:CreateInternal()
Firebase.FirebaseApp:<Create>m__0()
Firebase.FirebaseApp:CreateAndTrack(CreateDelegate, FirebaseApp)
Firebase.FirebaseApp:Create()
Firebase.FirebaseApp:get_DefaultInstance()
Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth:get_DefaultInstance()
EmailPassword:Start() (at Assets/Examples/Auth/EmailPassword.cs:19)
```

This is the EmailPassword.cs file code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Firebase.Auth;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System;

public class EmailPassword : MonoBehaviour
{

private FirebaseAuth auth;
public InputField UserNameInput, PasswordInput;
public Button SignupButton, LoginButton;
public Text ErrorText;

void Start()
{
    auth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
    //Just an example to save typing in the login form
    UserNameInput.text = "demofirebase@gmail.com";
    PasswordInput.text = "abcdefgh";

    SignupButton.onClick.AddListener(() => Signup(UserNameInput.text, PasswordInput.text));
    LoginButton.onClick.AddListener(() => Login(UserNameInput.text, PasswordInput.text));
}


public void Signup(string email, string password)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(email) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
    {
        //Error handling
        return;
    }

    auth.CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password).ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        if (task.IsCanceled)
        {
            Debug.LogError("CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync was canceled.");
            return;
        }
        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            Debug.LogError("CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync error: " + task.Exception);
            if (task.Exception.InnerExceptions.Count > 0)
                UpdateErrorMessage(task.Exception.InnerExceptions[0].Message);
            return;
        }

        FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result; // Firebase user has been created.
        Debug.LogFormat("Firebase user created successfully: {0} ({1})",
            newUser.DisplayName, newUser.UserId);
        UpdateErrorMessage("Signup Success");
    });
}

private void UpdateErrorMessage(string message)
{
    ErrorText.text = message;
    Invoke("ClearErrorMessage", 3);
}

void ClearErrorMessage()
{
    ErrorText.text = "";
}
public void Login(string email, string password)
{
    auth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password).ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        if (task.IsCanceled)
        {
            Debug.LogError("SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync canceled.");
            return;
        }
        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            Debug.LogError("SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync error: " + task.Exception);
            if (task.Exception.InnerExceptions.Count > 0)
                UpdateErrorMessage(task.Exception.InnerExceptions[0].Message);
            return;
        }

        FirebaseUser user = task.Result;
        Debug.LogFormat("User signed in successfully: {0} ({1})",
            user.DisplayName, user.UserId);

        PlayerPrefs.SetString("LoginUser", user != null ? user.Email : "Unknown");
        SceneManager.LoadScene("LoginResults");
    });
}
}
```

I download the Firebase Unity SDK from here https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup so I think I have the latest version.
And when I try the **Resolve** and the **Force Resolve** buttons in unity an error appears:

```
Resolving to Android package directory Assets\Plugins\Android instead of the requested target directory Assets/Plugins/Android

Is Assets\Plugins\Android in a different case to Assets/Plugins/Android ?

UnityEngine.Debug:LogWarning(Object)
Google.Logger:Log(String, LogLevel)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:Log(String, LogLevel)
GooglePlayServices.SettingsDialog:ValidatePackageDir(String)
GooglePlayServices.SettingsDialog:get_PackageDir()
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:OnPostprocessAllAssets(String[], String[], String[], String[])
UnityEditor.AssetDatabase:Refresh()
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:DeleteLabeledAssets()
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:ResolveUnsafe(Action`1, Boolean)
GooglePlayServices.<Resolve>c__AnonStorey11:<>m__19()
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:ExecuteNextResolveJob()
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:Resolve(Action, Boolean, Action`1)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:ExecuteMenuResolve(Boolean)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:MenuForceResolve()
```

Any help to solve the problem?

Comment: Sincerely, I don't get the reason for the number of downvotes this question got.

Comment: @Andreaジーティーオー I didn't downvote, but I understand the motivation - it's not actually clear what the question is. A debug statement is not an error statement. The user's self-answer is completely unrelated to anything we might have understood from the question.

Comment: Yes, you are right, and I'm sorry for that. But I think that it is an error because the signup button in my game does nothing when I click it, but the problem was that another object (Text in my case) was in front of it so I change its place and everything works fine.
I am sorry for this bad question.

Answer (score 0):

You've configured your SDK with forward slashes `/` instead of backwards slashes `\`, which are the appropriate directory marker for your operating system. Just change your SDK directory to `Assets\Plugins\Android`.

Comment: I change the system language from Arabic (RTL) to English (LTR), and this solves only the problem that appears after I click on "Force Resolve", but the first problem is not solved yet.